# using each method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a table which has input checkboxes.

When user selects checkbox I'm saving this `value` attribute to an `array`...so the user is clicking, checking and unchecking and after some time he will press the button.

In the button click event I'm trying to iterate through each of the records and check if the each `input[type="checkbox"]` has the same value as the one in the array, so if the values are the same then I will read all the `td` values from that row.

This is my code:

```
$('#something').click(function(){
$( "tr td input" ).each(function(index) {
   //selected is an array which has values collected from the checked checkboxes..for example [2,3]
   for(var i=0;i<selected.length;i++)
   {
    if($(this).val()==selected[i][0].value)
    {
            alert($('tr').eq(index).find('td').eq(1).text());
    }
   }
});
});
```

And html code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="on"></td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Steve</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So for example if I have value `[1]` in the array. How can I get all the row information from that? My code is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Could you add your button with the click event? I [copied your code into this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hH14ZaHShaoaCTE3cz7m?p=preview) we could use it as a base to find the solution.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I just did but it's not working

Comment: You can add the button an the function that is executed here as well. I will update the plunk then.

Comment: problem is that I'm not getting data as I should. First checkbox is giving me a headache

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert

Comment: If you also show us the code how the array "selected" was populated, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I understood the following: each time a checkbox is clicked the value is saved to an array, if the user clicks a button each array value is compared with the checkbox values;  if they are the same all the td values from that row will be saved into an array.

Comment: With the code you provided i get an error that `selected` is not defined. To help you with your code we need more of it and any error message you see in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [plunk that iterates over each input](http://embed.plnkr.co/hH14ZaHShaoaCTE3cz7m/preview), reads the values and writes them to an array:

```
  var checkBoxCollection = new Array();
  var cb = {};

  $("button").click(function(){      

        $("input").each(function(index, el){

          id = $(el).attr("id");
          val = $(el).val();
          isChecked = $(el).is(':checked');
          console.log(index, id, val);
          checkBoxCollection.push({'id': id, 'val': val, 'isChecked': isChecked});
        }); // each
        console.log(checkBoxCollection);
    }); // button.click
```

You could use this way to select the cell value as soon as the button is clicked and would only have to test if the box was checked. To learn how to use the console and the [chrome dev tools you may take a look at this 7 minute video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mf_yNLlgic)

#### Update with one checkbox for all

In my [updated plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/MicTssVPUUZC1m1S4x1o/preview) you can see that i use two different selectors

```
// using different selector - see my comment and tell me if you can not do that
Select all <input class="cbAll" type="checkbox" id="cbAll" value="on">
// and each checkbox like this
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" id="cb0" value="0">
```

And the javascript

```
  $("input.cbAll").click(function(){
    $("input.cb").each(function(index, el){
      // javascript ternary operator is optional this switches each checked state
      $(el).is(':checked') 
        ? $(el).prop('checked', false)
        : $(el).prop('checked', true);
    }); // each
  });
```

#### Update including the copy of the text inside the `<td>`

In [this plunk the text from the cells in the same tablerow of the checbox is copied](http://embed.plnkr.co/EGJj5DahceI3dfxhgSB3/preview) into the array. The relevant code are these lines

```
  isChecked = $(el).is(':checked');
  if(isChecked){
    var cells = $(el).parent().parent().children(); 
    var cellId = cells.eq(1).text();
    var cellName = cells.eq(2).text();
    checkBoxCollection.push({'id': id, 'val': val
              , 'isChecked': isChecked
              , 'cellId': cellId
              , 'cellName': cellName});
    console.log(index, id, val, cellId, cellName);
  }
```

In the screenshot you can see that the values of each checked textbox are copied.

[image]

As far as i can tell i solved all your questions:

- use of jquery each to iterate over checkboxes
- copy the text of cells within a tablerow into an array if the checkbox of that row is checked

If i understood your questions not fully please clarify what you would like to know.

Comment: thank you for your code, however my problems is in the first checkbox which has value `on` and it is used to select all checkboxes. So when I iterate trough the selected options first index is value `on` but then my other loop is not working as it should. I need to skip the first checkbox...so I need to skip `$(this).val()`

Comment: Could use a different selector? One for the first checkbox that selects or switches every of the following checkboxes? I will give you an example shortly

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the condition `if($(this).val()==selected[i][0].value)` is not true.

If it is a simple array, you don't need `.value` in the end. Simply compare with `selected[i][0]`

```
if($(this).val()==selected[i][0])
```